# Deviant grep behavior for Inverse matching

Tags: grep, inverse

I have a file containing identifiers (one per line) that I wish to run through an unspecified analysis. The analysis will, if everything runs perfectly, output another list with the same identifiers (not necessarily in the same order).

However, it turns out that the analysis was not done for some of the input identifiers and these are not present in the output file. This was because Internet connection went out and so the program skipped some of the identifiers and continued successfully further down the list when the Internet was back. This means that the identifiers that got skipped are interspersed in the input file.

So there will be some lines in the input file that is not present in the output file and I would like to extract these and re-run my analysis. This sounds like a simple grep -vf command, but here is where it gets a bit confusing.

I know that my input file has 100000 rows. I also know that my output file has 9000 rows. The difference should reasonably be 100000-90000 = 10000 identifiers. But when I run

```
fgrep -vf output input | wc-l
```

I get 9990 instead of 10000. So somewhere, 10 identifiers have gone missing. I have checked to see if the problem was due to Windows EOFs or tabs (have had other kinds of unexpected behavior from grep before due to this), but that was not the issue. My headers contain large and small letters, numbers and underscores but no other characters e. g.

```
Si_d14LSK_TRRt_Pmkk_comp10_c0_seq2
```

The output list of identifiers was generated by doing

```
ls -lh dir | sed "1d" | sed "/.* //" | sed "s/.xml//" > output
```

Where the previous step of the analysis produced a file for each of the input identifiers.

Does anyone know any contextual factors (like EOFs) that could cause such a deviant grep behavior? Or suggest another way to approach this instead of fgrep -vf?

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with GNU grep 2.10.

Comment: There is always the `awk` approach for this: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)' fileA fileB`. This shows all lines in `fileB` that do not appear in `fileA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "output" identifiers are probably matching substrings of the "input" file. For example, "output" contains `foo` and "input" contains both `foo` and `foobar`

You want one of

```sh
grep -Fvxf output input   # match a whole line
grep -Fvwf output input   # match a whole word
# ......^
```

Comment: This worked amazingly well! Some of my identifiers that ends with e. g. seq1 might very well match identifiers that are identical to the near end, but ends with seq12 or similar instead.